# Add a Subscribe to Blog link next to comments

Tags: rss, subscription

I would like to add a "Subscribe to Blog" link in my template so that readers can receive the blog via email or at the very least RSS. I've see many Wordpress Plugins that use a sidebar widget, but I'd like to have the link right at the bottom of the post.

Having it there seems to make the most sense to me.

so it looks something like"
Posted in Category | 5 Comments | Subscribe to Blog

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit your theme. Find the file where the loop of posts is being outputted; typically this will be in index.php. Find the place where the comments link is being output, and add:

```
 | <a href="<?php echo get_feed_link() ?>">Subscribe to Blog</a>
```